# Web scraping with beautifulSoup and selenium NBA stats

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

> Im trying to get the data for the NBA advanced stat but keep getting errors. This is what I have. Please help

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
d = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe')
d.get('https://www.nba.com/stats/players/passing/?Season=2019-20&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&TeamID=1610612747')
s = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find('table', {'class':'nba-stat-table__overflow'})
headers, [_, *data] = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('th')], [[i.text for i in soup.find_all('td')] for i in soup.find_all('tr')]
final_data = [i for i in data if len(i) > 1]
print(final_data)
```

Comment: Which is your error? Why use Selenium just to fetch the page source when you could simply fetch the webpage using requests? Please show us the error you have.

Comment: The site is dynamic, and my error is 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'table' with 'class'='table-responsive' , there is a 'div' element with 'class' = 'table-responsive' , and that has a 'table' underneath with 'class'='table'. So this line is returning a NoneType:

```
s = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').find('table', {'class':'table-responsive'})
```

Comment: Thank you @saint-jaeger ! Now I am getting 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'

Answer (score 0):

Just use pandas to read in the tables once you get the page source from selenium. Note you'll likely need to add a implicit wait for the page to render.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/kgrab/OneDrive/Desktop/web mining/week3-twitter/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
d.get('https://www.nba.com/stats/players/passing/?Season=2019-20&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&TeamID=1610612747')

df = pd.read_html(d.page_source)[0]
d.close()
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
                      Player Team  GP  ...  ASTAdj  AST ToPass%  AST ToPass% Adj
0                Alex Caruso  LAL  64  ...     2.3          8.0              9.6
1              Anthony Davis  LAL  62  ...     3.9          8.3              9.9
2              Avery Bradley  LAL  49  ...     1.6          6.8              8.4
3                Danny Green  LAL  68  ...     1.7          4.7              5.8
4             Devontae Cacok  LAL   1  ...     1.0         16.7             16.7
5               Dion Waiters  LAL   7  ...     3.6          9.8             14.5
6              Dwight Howard  LAL  69  ...     0.8          2.8              3.2
7                   JR Smith  LAL   6  ...     0.7          6.0              8.0
8               JaVale McGee  LAL  68  ...     0.7          3.3              4.4
9               Jared Dudley  LAL  45  ...     0.8          5.7              7.0
10  Kentavious Caldwell-Pope  LAL  69  ...     1.8          7.5              8.6
11      Kostas Antetokounmpo  LAL   5  ...     0.6         11.8             17.6
12                Kyle Kuzma  LAL  61  ...     1.6          6.4              7.9
13              LeBron James  LAL  67  ...    11.8         16.4             19.0
14           Markieff Morris  LAL  14  ...     0.8          4.1              5.7
15                Quinn Cook  LAL  44  ...     1.1          8.3              8.5
16               Rajon Rondo  LAL  48  ...     6.1         12.7             15.5
17       Talen Horton-Tucker  LAL   6  ...     2.0          5.7             11.3
18              Troy Daniels  DEN  41  ...     0.5          6.3              9.0
19          Zach Norvell Jr.  GSW   2  ...     0.0          0.0              0.0

[20 rows x 16 columns]
```